# Mi procedimiento almacenado no funciona, pero al ejecutar la consulta por si sola, si lo hace

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_proveedores
AS
SELECT * FROM ganaderos g
```

Al ejecutarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
EXEC sp_proveedores
```

SQL Server 2012, se queda procesando, espero por horas y el procedimiento no temrina de ejecutar. Debo mencionar que la tabla solo tiene 5mil registros.

Lo estraño es, que si ejecuto la consulta por si sola:

```
SELECT * FROM ganaderos g
```

La sentencia se ejecuta en menos de 3 segundos.
Alguien sabe que podria estar pasando.

Para solucionar el problema tengo que reiniciar el servidor o todo el servicio de SQL.

Comment: Intenta cambiar el prefijo del procedimiento almacenado. El prefijo `sp_` está asignado para los objetos especial de SQL Server.

Comment: Desde dónde ejecutas el procedimiento? Desde dónde lo creas? Ves algo en las sesiones activas de la BD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de eliminar todos los indices de las tablas, los volvi a crear y ahora todo funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar el prefijo del procedimiento almacenado. El prefijo `sp_` está asignado para los objetos especial de SQL Server.

Fuera de eso, solo se me ocurre que pueda estar bloqueada la tabla por algún proceso. Pero sería raro que funcionara la consulta por si misma, a menos de que en esa misma conexión tengas una transacción abierta.

Comment: Hice lo que comentas, cambie el prefijo sp, pero no funciona.

Comment: Es muy extraño en realidad, pues la consulta fuera del procedimiento funciona rapido.